# How to pass an image sequence through a ConvNet in Pytorch (Similar to Keras' TimeDistributed Layer)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, video-processing

I'm trying to translate a video frame classification script that I wrote in Keras to Pytorch, however I'm stuck.

My input is a sequence of 20 consecutive frames with shape: `(batchsize, seq_len, channels, img_height, img_width)`, and i'm looking to pass each frame through EfficientNet feature extraction layers, concat the output from all timesteps and then pass through LSTM units and Dense layers, to make predictions on each frame in the sequence. i.e the shape of the output should be `(batchsize, seq_len, 1)`.

In keras I wrote it like this:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(20,3,224,224))
convnet = efficientnet_without_top(shape=(3,224,224)

x = TimeDistributed(convnet)(inputs) # output shape = (20, 1560)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(x) # output shape = (20, 128)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32)](x) # output shape = (20, 32)
x = keras.layers.Dense(1)](x) # output shape = (20, 1)
```

How do I write this 'time distributed' step in Pytorch?

Comment: I think the naive approach would be to simply reshape the input from [B, T, C, H W] to [B * T, C, H, W] then pass through the network and when you get an output of shape [B * T, ...] just reshape it to [B, T, ...]. The only issue with this approach would be that batch operations (like batch norm) would be applied to all elements the same. In the case of batch normalization, this means that rather than a different mean/var for each timestep it would use a single mean/var computed from all timesteps. Im not convinced this would necessarily be a bad thing, but it would depend on your usecase.

Comment: @jodag this is an excellent point. let me try this.. it may be as simple as you say.

Comment: @jodag, why wont you post that as an answer?